# Trying a game with Python, the function for images?

Tags: python

I didnt watched the full tutorial for learning Python, but I'm learning how to use pygame. I know a few things about Python but not so much
I'm now trying to put a background image and the tutorial says that I have to use this function:

```
def load_image(filename, transparent=False):
        try: image = pygame.image.load(filename)
        except pygame.error, message:
                raise SystemExit, message
        image = image.convert()
        if transparent:
                color = image.get_at((0,0))
                image.set_colorkey(color, RLEACCEL)
        return image
```

but in my editor (Pyscripter) the line `except pygame.error, message:` has a sintaxis error I don't know why and if I delete it the line that starts with raise has a sintaxis error too... what can I do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: Tip: learn the language first, the libraries later. Watching bits of video tutorials here and there isn't going to teach you anything valuable.

Comment: I know right, but the tutorial says that doesn't matter if I don't know a lot of Python 'cause they will explain it.

Comment: What version of Python are you on?

Comment: Pyscripter is on ver. 2.5.3.0 x86 and Python is on ver. 3.3.2

Comment: The tutorial you're following probably assumes python 2.7, not 3.x... pygame says it 'mostly' works with 3.x, but not completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the old syntax for `except`.  The new way uses `as`:

```
except pygame.error as message:
```

The old way was removed as of Python 3.x.  See below:

```
>>> try:
...     1/0
... except ZeroDivisionError, e:
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    except ZeroDivisionError, e:
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> try:
...     1/0
... except ZeroDivisionError as e:
...     print(e)
...
division by zero
>>>
```

Also, your syntax for the `raise` statement is wrong.  It should be:

```
raise SystemExit(message)
```

See below:

```
>>> raise ZeroDivisionError, "NO!"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    raise ZeroDivisionError, "NO!"
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> raise ZeroDivisionError("NO!")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: NO!
>>>
```

So, your final code should look like this:

```
except pygame.error as message:
    raise SystemExit(message)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked with `except` but ´raise SystemExit, message´ has now a Syntax Error..... how can I solve it, can you say me please? and Thanks!

Comment: That solved all of my problems! Thank you very much, I'm learning a lot from this page, and his users!! Thanks! :D